# Execute mySQL query into Laravel SQL query?

Tags: mysql, laravel

I have an SQL query and I want to convert it to Laravel query style. I tried to convert it, but I got empty data when it tries to run into Heidi SQL. With this query I got the result I want. The problem is I don't know what's wrong with my query after I convert it into Laravel style.

```sql
SELECT agency_name, count(document_id) as bil_doc 
from user_documents, email_deliveries, users, agencies  
where email_deliveries.id=email_delivery_id 
and email_deliveries.created_by_id=users.id 
and users.agency_id=agencies.id and 
YEAR(send_date)='2021'  
group by agency_id 
order by agencies.priority
```

Hereafter I'm converting to Laravel query style:

```
$docSend = DB::table('user_documents')
    ->whereYear('email_deliveries.send_date', $currentYear)
    ->join('email_deliveries', 'email_deliveries.id', '=', 'user_documents.email_delivery_id')
    ->join('users', 'users.id', '=', 'email_deliveries.created_by_id')
    ->join('agencies', 'agencies.id', '=', 'users.agency_id')
    ->select(DB::raw('count(user_documents.document_id) as bil_doc'), 'agency_name', 'agencies.priority')
    ->where('user_documents.email_delivery_id', '=', 'email_deliveries.id')
    ->where('email_deliveries.created_by_id', '=', 'users.id')
    ->where('users.agency_id', '=', 'agencies.id')
    ->groupBy('agency_name', 'agencies.priority')
    ->orderBy('agencies.priority', 'ASC')
    ->get();
```

Answer (score 0):

In Laravel's query builder, the second/third argument passed to `where()` is interpreted as a string so it searches for the string instead of the column. To achive this, you need to use `whereColumn()`:

```
$docSend = DB::table('user_documents')
    ->whereYear('email_deliveries.send_date', $currentYear)
    ->join('email_deliveries', 'email_deliveries.id', '=', 'user_documents.email_delivery_id')
    ->join('users', 'users.id', '=', 'email_deliveries.created_by_id')
    ->join('agencies', 'agencies.id', '=', 'users.agency_id')
    ->select(DB::raw('count(user_documents.document_id) as bil_doc'), 'agency_name', 'agencies.priority')
    ->whereColumn('user_documents.email_delivery_id', '=', 'email_deliveries.id')
    ->whereColumn('email_deliveries.created_by_id', '=', 'users.id')
    ->whereColumn('users.agency_id', '=', 'agencies.id')
    ->groupBy('agency_name', 'agencies.priority')
    ->orderBy('agencies.priority', 'ASC')
    ->get();
```

Additionally, you duplicated your code by doing JOINs (you don't do that in your original query) but also do FROM + WHERE. So your query would really look like this:

```
$docSend = DB::table('user_documents')
    ->whereYear('email_deliveries.send_date', $currentYear)
    ->join('email_deliveries', 'email_deliveries.id', '=', 'user_documents.email_delivery_id')
    ->join('users', 'users.id', '=', 'email_deliveries.created_by_id')
    ->join('agencies', 'agencies.id', '=', 'users.agency_id')
    ->select(DB::raw('count(user_documents.document_id) as bil_doc'), 'agency_name', 'agencies.priority')
    ->groupBy('agency_name', 'agencies.priority')
    ->orderBy('agencies.priority', 'ASC')
    ->get();
```